# In webRTC no frame transmitted to browser from C++ code after calling onFrame in the capturer

Tags: c++, webrtc

I am trying to make my app up to date with webrtc. This is basically a desktop streaming application with a C++ application video streaming to a browser using webRTC.
My implementation used to use a bunch of deprecated stuff like `SignalFrameCaptured` and `cricket::CapturedFrame`.
Looking at webRTC right now it seems those classes/signals are not available.

Here is my capturer:

```
class Capturer
: public cricket::VideoCapturer,
  public webrtc::DesktopCapturer::Callback
{

 public:

   sigslot::signal1<Capturer*> SignalDestroyed;

   Capturer();
   ~Capturer();

   void ResetSupportedFormats(const std::vector<cricket::VideoFormat>& formats);
   bool CaptureFrame();
   cricket::CaptureState Start(const cricket::VideoFormat& format) override;
   void Stop() override;
   bool IsRunning() override;
   bool IsScreencast() const override;
   bool GetPreferredFourccs(std::vector<uint32_t>* fourccs) override;


   virtual void OnCaptureResult(webrtc::DesktopCapturer::Result result,

                         std::unique_ptr<webrtc::DesktopFrame> desktop_frame) override;


 private:
   bool running_;
   int64_t initial_timestamp_;
   int64_t next_timestamp_;
   std::unique_ptr<webrtc::DesktopCapturer> _capturer;

};
```

`Capturer::CaptureFrame()` is called periodically from another thread and `Capturer::OnCaptureResult` is called as expected with a `DesktopFrame` as parameter.
Now looking at the implementation of `OnCaptureResult`:

```
void Capturer::OnCaptureResult(webrtc::DesktopCapturer::Result result,

                          std::unique_ptr<webrtc::DesktopFrame> desktopFrame)
{

  if (result != webrtc::DesktopCapturer::Result::SUCCESS)
  {
   return; // Never called. Which leads me to conclude thedesktop capturer works
  }


  int width = desktopFrame->size().width();
  int height = desktopFrame->size().height();
  rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::I420Buffer> res_i420_frame = webrtc::I420Buffer::Create(width, height);


  webrtc::ConvertToI420(webrtc::VideoType::kABGR,
                        desktopFrame->data(),
                        0, 0,
                        width, height,
                        0,
                        webrtc::kVideoRotation_0,
                        res_i420_frame);

  webrtc::VideoFrame frame = webrtc::VideoFrame(res_i420_frame, webrtc::kVideoRotation_0, next_timestamp_ / rtc::kNumNanosecsPerMicrosec);


  this->OnFrame(frame, width, height);
}
```

No frame are ever transmitted to the connected browser, as seen from chrome::webrtc-internals.

[image: No incoming video stream]

Back to the code, here is how I create the peerConnection:

```
void Conductor::connectToPeer() {

  this->_peerConnectionFactory = webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory();

  if (!this->_peerConnectionFactory.get())
  {
     std::cerr << "Failed to initialize PeerConnectionFactory" << std::endl;
     throw new std::runtime_error("Cannot initialize PeerConnectionFactory");
  }   

  webrtc::PeerConnectionInterface::RTCConfiguration config;
  webrtc::PeerConnectionInterface::IceServer server;
  server.uri = "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302";
  config.servers.push_back(server);

  webrtc::FakeConstraints       constraints;constraints.AddOptional(webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::kEnableDtlsSrtp, "true");

  this->_peerConnection = this->_peerConnectionFactory->CreatePeerConnection(config, &constraints, NULL, NULL, this);

  if (!this->_peerConnection.get())
  {
      std::cerr << "Failed to initialize PeerConnection" << std::endl;
      throw new std::runtime_error("Cannot initialize PeerConnection");
  }


 auto capturer = new Capturer();

 CapturerThread *capturerThread = new CapturerThread(capturer); // This thread sole functionis to call CaptureFrameperiodically


 rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::VideoTrackSourceInterface> videoSource = this->_peerConnectionFactory->CreateVideoSource(capturer, NULL);
 rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::VideoTrackInterface> videoTrack(this->_peerConnectionFactory->CreateVideoTrack("video_label", videoSource));
 rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::MediaStreamInterface> stream = this->_peerConnectionFactory->CreateLocalMediaStream("stream_label");  

 stream->AddTrack(videoTrack);
 if (!this->_peerConnection->AddStream(stream))
 {
    std::cerr << "Adding stream to PeerConnection failed" << std::endl;
    throw new std::runtime_error("Cannot add stream");
 }

 typedef std::pair<std::string,rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::MediaStreamInterface>> MediaStreamPair;

 this->_activeStreams.insert(MediaStreamPair(stream->label(), stream));
 webrtc::SdpParseError error;

 webrtc::SessionDescriptionInterface* sessionDescription(webrtc::CreateSessionDescription("offer", this->_offer, &error));

 if (!sessionDescription)
 {
    std::cerr << "Cannot initialize session description." << std::endl;
    throw new std::runtime_error("Cannot set session description");
 }


 this->_peerConnection->SetRemoteDescription(DummySetSessionDescriptionObserver::Create(), sessionDescription);

 this->_peerConnection->CreateAnswer(this, NULL);
}
```

My problem is no video frames are even transmitted to the browser client even though both the capturer and the peer connection are in place as expected. Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Well, Sir, It's really informative question. Sir, Can you please assist me in this situation. I am doing the same thing. My Offer Answer mechanism is 100 % working and Data is being shared over Data Channel. I am unable to send Video Frames to the browser. I am dealing with the same implementation just for learning purposes. Sir, Can you please assist me in this matter or you can share your GitHub repository in which this module has been implemented by you?

I am very close to the things, your assistance might help me a lot, Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this. The local description was simply not set after creating the answer.

Calling `createAnswer` will hopefully trigger the `OnSuccess` callback in the `CreateSessionDescriptionObserver` (in my case `Conductor`).

There I failed to save the answer as the local description. Here is how the `OnSuccess` method should be implemented:

```
void Conductor::OnSuccess(webrtc::SessionDescriptionInterface *desc)
{    
  this->_peerConnection->SetLocalDescription(DummySetSessionDescriptionObserver::Create(), desc);
}
```

Doing this will ultimately trigger `OnIceGatheringChange` with `kIceGatheringComplete` as parameter, meaning both sides are ready.

Answer (score 1):

According with google group discuss-webrtc [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/37TSGD6JXuM)

you should implement VideoTrackSourceInterface. In my case, I used the base class AdaptedVideoTrackSource and I created a method FrameCaptured it's is called from my thread. In the method FrameCaptured I call the base method OnFrame. It's work fine !!!

```
 class StreamSource : public rtc::AdaptedVideoTrackSource
 {
   void OnFrameCaptured(const webrtc::VideoFrame& frame);
 }

 void StreamSource::OnFrameCaptured(const webrtc::VideoFrame& frame) 
 {
   OnFrame(frame);
 }
```